# Multiple data check in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I have the following problem. I have 2 tables in the database - table1 and table2.

```
Table1
id| val1| val2
--------------
1 | 234 | 342
2 | 325 | 356
...

Table2
id | uid | val 
--------------
1  | 5   | 234
2  | 6   | 362
3  | 5   | 123
```

I would like to check for each record in table2 if val exists in table1 (`table2.val=table1.va1 or table2.val > table1.vall`). 
In table1 is about 2 million records. In table2 several thousand.
If query result true i'd like to remove rows from table2.

Is it possible to do this in one query? mysql or postgresql

Performance is very important.

Comment: There's no column in Table1 called `val`

Comment: "for each record in table2 if val exists in table2" surely one of those should be `table1`!

Comment: Also, we need information about how to join these tables e.g. does `uid` in `Table2` reference `id` in `Table1`?

Comment: In fact, uid refers to another table. These two tables are not linked to any key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `(t2.val = t1.val1) or (t1.val2 > t2.val)` conditions:

```
delete table2
from table2 t2
inner join table1 t1 on (t2.val = t1.val1) or (t1.val2 > t2.val)
```

Comment: Execution time is 161 seconds. Is it possible to execute this query faster?

Answer (score 0):

```
delete t 
from #table2 t 
inner join #table1 t2 
on t.val = t2.val or t2.val>t.val
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `uid` in `Table2` reference `id` in `Table1` (and that neither table contain nulls), this returns the rows in `Table1` that satisfy your existence criteria:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table1
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM Table2 
                WHERE Table2.uid = Table1.id
                      AND (
                           Table2.val = Table1.val1
                           OR Table2.val > Table1.val2
                          )
              );
```